# Dwr callback "data" object length

Tags: java, javascript, callback, dwr

I'm using dwr to handle ajax calls to a java backend, I'm returning a Map in java, and I need to know its size in javascript when it returns in a callback function. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Could you post some (JS) code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to know how to determine the size of a javascript associative array, because this is what dwr returns in this case. This is explained, of course,  on Stack Overflow:
[Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-associative-array)